# Visual Studio Project Properties 2013

Tags: visual-studio

so I messed up some project properties (values in VC++ Directories and so on) and dont know how to go back. Is there any way to get back to default properties (same when I installed visual studio). ReInstallation did not help.

Comment: Most project settings have an "Inherit from parent or project defaults" option. For the various "VC++ Directories", that's a checkbox in the dialog you see when you select "Edit" from the drop-down menu you see when clicking the wee arrow at the right of the text field. Does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Errors that I'm getting =>"Cannot open include file "winsock2.h" "Cannot open include file "string" and many others like this